# Rails, how to make a database model that records last accessed time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to make a rails model that records last_time_accessed as an attribute. So whenever I access an instance, the current time will be saved. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an after_find, after_initialize or after_touch module callback. Decide what fits your needs best. But I think it's ugly and be aware, thus you can stress your database with a lot of write requests.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :update_last_time_accessed

  private

  def update_last_time_accessed
    update_attribute(:last_time_accessed, Time.now)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best with the [`after_touch`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/guides/source/active_record_callbacks.md#after_touch) callback:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_touch :set_time

  private

  def set_time
    self.update last_time_accessed: Time.now
  end
end
```

You'll have to accommodate an extra db request being sent every time you access that model's data.